# Выбор заявок

Tags: c++

Не могли бы вы помочь с задачей? Написал свое решение, но оно не верно. Вот задача.

Входные данные

> В первой строке задано число N (1 <= N <= 100000) --- количество отрезков. Далее заданы сами отрезки парами целых чисел --- левым и правым концом. Координаты концов лежат в диапазоне от 1 до 10^9.

Выходные данные

> Выведите количество отрезков в искомом множестве. Далее выведите сами отрезке в порядке возрастания левого конца.

Пример

> Ввод 3  10 12  1 5  3 7
>
> Вывод 2  3 7  10 12

Вот мое решение. Yо оно не работает. Я в упор не могу понять, почему ответ 3 7 и 10 12, а не 2 (3 7)(10 12) и (1 5 )(10 12).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int n;
int xy[100000][2];
int sum[100000][2];
int sum1[100000][2];
int nam;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j;
    nam = 0;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> xy[i][1] >> xy[i][2];

    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int b = j; b < n; b++) {
            if ((xy[j][1] < xy[b][1]) && (xy[j][2] < xy[b][1]) || xy[j][1] > xy[b][2]) {
                sum[j][1] = xy[j][1];
                sum[j][2] = xy[j][2];
                sum1[j][1] = xy[b][1];
                sum1[j][2] = xy[b][2];
                nam++;
                cout << sum[j][1] << " " << sum[j][2] << " " << endl << sum1[j][1] << " " << sum1[j][2] << endl;
            }

        }

    }

    cout << nam;
}
```

Покажите плз на примере кода 2 день не могу написать:(

Comment: (1 5) (10 12) также будет правильным ответом. Но все равно - 2 отрезка.

Comment: Ну потому что вам нужно найти подмножество (по идее ответ (1 5) (10 12) тоже подходит). Общая идея решения, мне кажется, будет динамика (предварительно надо будет отсортировать только).

Comment: @Not even close, похоже в результате правок цель (что надо сделать)

    Найдите наибольшее подмножество > попарно непересекающихся отрезков. 

из вопроса пропала.

--

Вообще я не совсем понимаю, что значит "попарно непересекающиеся отрезки", в основном неясен смысл **попарно**. Видимо поэтому я тоже в недоумении, почему именно (10 12)(3 7), а не (10 12)(1 5)?

Единственное предположение, что 3 в (3 7) больше 1 в (1 5), а в условии говорится о порядке вывода. 

Может быть это требование надо распространить на выбор из (1 5),(3 7) в пару к (10 12) ???

Answer (score 1):

Так Вам нужно найти **непересекающиеся** отрезки. Собственно поэтому-то ответ 2.